# Free JDBC tools can't connect but DataGrip can

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, dbeaver

I'm trying to connect to an SSL encrypted database hosted on GCP. I've tried DBeaver which gives me multiple types of errors depending on the authentication chosen. I've tried all combinations. I have files: client-key.pem, client-key.pem, server-ca.pem.

I get "unable to find valid certification path to requested target", even though I've added the server-ca.pem file to the JDK's lib/security/cacerts keystore and specified

```
-Djavax.net.ssltruststore=/home/bpracht/java/jdk-17.0.2/lib/security/cacerts
```

to the dbeaver.ini file.

Further, I don't see why I'd need to add probably one of the world's most major internet companies to a trust chain as though no one has ever heard of Google or GCP. But, I did.

Settings:
Host: <ip address from public address in GCP>
Port: 5432
Database: postgres-dev (named ID)
Username: mydb-dev
Password: mypassword
Driver name: PostgreSQL

Driver properties:

```
ssl=true
sslfactory=org.postgresql.sslDefaultJavaSSLFactory
Use SSL is checked
CA Cerfificate: /home/woodsman/postgres-server-ca.pem
Client Certificate: /home/woodsman/postgres-client-cert.pem
Client Private Key: /home/woodsman/postgres-client-key.pem
SSL mode: verify-ca (also tried required, got same result)
SSL Factory:org.postgresql.sslDefaultJavaSSLFactory
```

Testing the connection gives me:

```
SSL error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Can someone just tell me the magic incantation to use for DBeaver+SSL+Postgres? This works fine on DataGrip, which is a good product, but DBeaver *would* be free and passable if *it worked*.

By the way, I have no way of knowing all the parms on datagrip. Why?

Comment: What errors do you get if you use the more familiar (to me) org.postgresql.ssl.LibPQFactory?

Comment: @jjanes I get the same error with org.postgresql.ssl.LibPQFactory (and verify-ca)

Comment: I don't see datagrip being different from dbeaver with org.postgresql.ssl.LibPQFactory in this regard.  They both give the error message you report when given the wrong cert for server-ca.pem, and both work when given the correct one.  But I also never tried changing the  dbeaver.ini file, maybe doing that broke something.

Answer (score 0):

For those who run into this problem, the answer was *not* adding a key to the Java keystore contrary to a previous SO response. The real answer was converting the .crt file into a pk8 file for the client key.